# How can I make img scaling and centered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with making a image scaled and centered. I want to make the image (with the text design&code) something like: [Example](http://salleedesign.com/home/) I looked up on the web for this, and I made many examples and I can't do this My last version  is [my version](http://stecudesign.pl/img/) When I change browser view for smallest image is not centered like on saaleedesign.com How can I make img in div centered after browser resize ?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you should set the background position to center.

html:

```
<div class="container">Text</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
   background-image: url("img.jpg");
   height: [some-height]px;
   width: 100%;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to **really** center it:

### DEMO - **http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK**

*Below is a very crude, minimalist example of how to use on the body tag*

### HTML

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

### CSS

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:100%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%); 
}

img.max{ width:auto; height:100%; }

/* RESET & stuff */
html, body{ height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
*{ margin:0; padding:0; }
```

### JS

```
// this part detects when the window width is too narrow for the current image aspect-ratio, and fits it to height 100% instead of width 100%.
var photo     = document.images[0],
    container = document.body;

$(window).on('resize.coverPhoto', function(){
  requestAnimationFrame(checkRatio);
});

function checkRatio(){
  var state = photo.clientHeight <= container.clientHeight && 
              photo.clientWidth >= container.clientWidth;
  
  photo.classList[state ? 'add' : 'remove']('max');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify whatever width you want for the image.

The whole trick is based on using a percentage measure.

This is a pretty simple solution and works in every browser whatever version it has.

Example:

```css
  html, body{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%
        display: block;
    }
    
    img{
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
   <body>
       <img src="http://simswiki.info/images/f/f8/Under_construction.png" width="50%">
   </body>
```

Comment: How do you get the two buttons to appear and work like this? I've never seen this on SO before!

Comment: [Lee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3359782/lee) Check this link [code snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1)